# Using "helper classes" in winforms, C#

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I tried to ask a question yesterday but it was seemingly too vague. Here's another try.

In the past, I have used some winforms/VB.Net classes with functionality for, say, working on text strings, for file operations, or for database handling, like clsStrings, clsIO and clsDB. The idea was that these classes did everything related to the subject, so that clsStrings would have a method called "filterString", removeCertainChars" etc.

In the old winforms application, I simply wrote Imports clsStrings when I needed to access a method. Throughout the .vb file, I could then write something like

```
str = filterString(TextBox1.Text)
```

I now try to get the same functionality in a new winforms app in C#. The only thing I get to work is creating a variable for the class:

```
clsStrings clsstrings = New clsStrings();
```

...and then later in the code:

```
str = clsstrings.filterString(TextBox1.Text);
```

So I guess what I would want is the ability to use a using statement for these "helper classes" (is there a better word for them?) so that I wouldn't have to write the variable name all the time. (Just like when Intellisense discovers that a namespace is missing and asks if I want to have a using statement for, say, System.Data so I can write "DataTable" instead of having to write "Data.Datatable" all the time.)

I suspect I would need to put these class files in a separate folder or so, but that would be totally fine. I just want some structure to my app.

I hope this is clearer.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: I think you are actually looking for [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) so you can write `TextBox1.Text.MyCustomExtensionMethod()`.

Comment: Have you looked at namespaces? and putting the namespace in your using blocks. Also, all these methods seem to be utility, you might be better off creating these as static methods, so that you dont really need to instantiate a class. Of course, I do not have the complete controx of your clsStrings or clsIO.

Comment: There is also `static` methods, which the equivalent modifier in VB.NET is `Shared`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the difference is that now you are working with OOP principles.

What you could do to be closer to what you were used to is to build static classes for the helper class, maybe even turn them into extension methods.

Example:

```
public static class ClsStrings
{

 public static string FilterString(this string stringToFilter) { return something; }

}
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
string filteredString = TextBox1.Text.filterString();
```

or

```
string filteredString = ClsStrings.filterString(TextBox1.Text);
```

Comment: dutzu wrote "...what you could do...". Does this mean that there would be an even better OOP-based solution? I now use dutzu's code and it works very well.

Comment: @user2040543 -  Well it's my preferred way and it's closest to what you were used to. There are other approaches, like the one you wrote in the question itself but the best one is the one that suits your needs better. If it's this one, with extension methods then this is the best way. Please mark the answer as correct if it's the correct one for you.

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods is the way to go here. Using these you can basically exten String class with your own methods and do something like Sting.filterString();

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx